# moving pointer between vectors in vector causes vector iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have `std::vector` of cells. Each cell has other `std::vector` to store some pointers to entities. Now I want to move pointer from one cell to another based on calculation new cell index.
But I am getting `vector iterators incompatible`. I know that is caused by `push_back` invalid the iterator, but I do not know why, because `push_back` doesn't manipulate with current existing `entityIter`. How should I modified the following example to make it work?

```
    for(uint32 cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < m_cells.size(); ++cellIndex)
    {
        std::vector<entity_type> & entitiesInCurrentCell = m_cells[cellIndex].entities;
        std::vector<entity_type>::iterator entityIter = entitiesInCurrentCell.begin();
        while(entityIter != entitiesInCurrentCell.end())
        {
            entity_type entity = *entityIter;
            uint32 entityNewIndex = calculateIndex(entity->getPosition());

            if(entityNewIndex == cellIndex) 
            {
                ++entityIter;
                continue;
            }

            m_cells[entityNewIndex].entities.push_back(entity);
            entitiesInCurrentCell.erase(entityIter++);
        }
    }
```

`entity_type` is a pointer type which point to entity allocated elsewhere, I do not want to delete it, just move the pointer between cells.

(I know this approach is not the best way - relocating pointer to higher-index cell causes recalculation it - but this is aim of this question)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that erases from `entitiesInCurrentCell` has a bug. Correct it by writing

```
entityIter = entitiesInCurrentCell.erase(entityIter);
```

When erasing from a container, the next iterator is returned by the erase function, so you do not need to increment the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Erasing from std::vector invalidates iterators. see [STL vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) Therefore entityIter is invalid after the call to erase. Alas the check "while(entityIter != entitiesInCurrentCell.end())" will never become true.

change your code to:

```
if(entityNewIndex == cellIndex) 
{
  ++entityIter;
}
else 
{
  m_cells[entityNewIndex].entities.push_back(entity);
  entityIter = entitiesInCurrentCell.erase(entityIter);
}
```